# Are Base64 encoded UUIDs unique?

Tags: java, base64, uuid

This is an extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30429168/10789057)

If the string which is being encoded is guaranteed to be unique, for example, a UUID , does this also mean that the base64 encoded string is also guaranteed to be unique?

If we consider the following Java example,

```
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16])
            .putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits())
            .putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());

    String encodedUUID = Base64.getUrlEncoder()
                  .withoutPadding()
                  .encodeToString(byteBuffer.array());
```

Since `uuid` is unique, does this imply `encodedUUID` will also be unique? If so what are chances of collision in case of a large number of encoded UUIDs?

Comment: I'd suggest that you edit your question. If your question is about Base64 string, it is already answered and your question should be closed as **duplicate**. If your question is about uniqueness and collisions, it is OK, then please delete the part related to Base64 strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the data is unique, it will be unique when base64 encoded.

Base64 encoding is a lossless representation of the encoded data. It's the same data, just represented using different symbols to encode it in a fairly high density, printable way.

Answer (score 3):

Base64 is bidirectional which means that if you encode a unique UUID, you are given a base64 string that can be decoded to exact one, in this case unique, value.