# Different results after encoding/decoding base64

Tags: c#, encoding, base64

I have the following base64 string:

```
R1NNQiBBZ2VuY3kgR21iSCAvIFdlYmRlc2lnbiBBZ2VudHVyIFVsbSAvIE9ubGluZXNob3AgQWdlbnR1ciAvIEFwcCBBZ2VudHVyIFVsbSwgR2VybWFueS==
```

And using an online base64 decoder I get the following result:

```
GSMB Agency GmbH / Webdesign Agentur Ulm / Onlineshop Agentur / App Agentur Ulm, Germany
```

All good, right? But now if I try to convert this text back to base64 - the result is becomes

```
R1NNQiBBZ2VuY3kgR21iSCAvIFdlYmRlc2lnbiBBZ2VudHVyIFVsbSAvIE9ubGluZXNob3AgQWdlbnR1ciAvIEFwcCBBZ2VudHVyIFVsbSwgR2VybWFueQ==
```

Any ideas?

This is the C# code I am using for decoding:

```
string basestring = "R1NNQiBBZ2VuY3kgR21iSCAvIFdlYmRlc2lnbiBBZ2VudHVyIFVsbSAvIE9ubGluZXNob3AgQWdlbnR1ciAvIEFwcCBBZ2VudHVyIFVsbSwgR2VybWFueS==";

string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(basestring));

return output;
```

And here's the encoding part

```
string basestring = "GSMB Agency GmbH / Webdesign Agentur Ulm / Onlineshop Agentur / App Agentur Ulm, Germany";

string output = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(basestring));

return output;
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Is a base64 encoded string unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30429168/11082165)

Comment: I removed the encryption tag because this question has nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: Sounds like one of these encoders is using an uninitialized variable. But that shouldn't matter in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually an artefact of moving from 8-bit encoding (UTF8) to a 6-bit encoding (Base64).
As reference, here's the [Base64 encoding table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table_from_RFC_4648)

We'll take an example of the string `"AB"`; `A` and `B` are char(`65` and `66`) respectively. In 8-bit binary grouping, 65/66 are `01000001/01000010`.

##### Encoding

When encoding to Base64, the same bits of your string are separated in groups of 6 instead of 8. So the same 16-bit sequence above are split into `010000/010100/0010` (same bit pattern, just grouped differently).

Now, the first two groups are easy. You look up the encoding table linked above, and you'll see that `010000 = Q` / `010100 = U`. You then have the last group with only 4 bits instead of the expected 6. This is where things get interesting.

When **encoding**, the end is usually padded with zeroes to get to 6 bits. So your `0010` becomes `001000` which is `I`. So `"AB"` when encoded in Base64 become `"QUI="`. The `=` is optional, it's just there to make the number of characters multiples of 4.

##### Decoding

Remember when your last group of `0010` is padded to become 6 bits? Here's the fun part: they don't have to be zeroes. The 16-bits (2x8) in your original string became 18-bits (3x6) because of the padding. Since 18 is not a multiple of 8 (bits), the encoder/decoder know enough to drop the excess bits. So the two bit padding could be *anything*, and they'll still decode properly.

`0010` when padded could either be `001000`, `001001`, `001010`, or `001011` - which translates to `I, J, K, or L`.  Bring up any decoder, and try decoding `QUI`, `QUJ`, `QUK`, and `QUL`. They will all decode to `"AB"`

##### Your string

Now, your string when split 6-bit groups looks like the following (see [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KDjkm4)):

```
var basestring = "GSMB Agency GmbH / Webdesign Agentur Ulm / Onlineshop Agentur / App Agentur Ulm, Germany";
var sixBitGroups = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(basestring)
  .SelectMany(b => $"{Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8,'0')}")
  .Chunk(6)
  .Select(c => new string(c.ToArray()));
string.Join("/", sixBitGroups).Dump();
```

You'll notice that it ends with `../01`. That `01` needs to be padded with 4 extra bits. Again, usually, they're zeroes, making it `010000` which is `Q`. So you'll see your encoded string ends with `..FueQ==`. But when you realise that they don't have to be all zeroes, you'll see in the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table_from_RFC_4648) that `01xxxx` covers everything from `Q,R,S, .. i,j`. This explains why your base64 `..FueS==` still decode to the exact same string.

Comment: Nice, thank you for such an in-depth answer, will definitely be helpful to know in the future!

Comment: Just a side note: These padding bits could be abused to send hidden information if a high amount of base64 strings could be generated and send.