# Why is a JWT signature not unique for a specific payload

Tags: base64, digital-signature, jwt, hmac

My application is using JWT and should prevent replay attacks. I was testing this an ran into the following.

When I have a valid JWT and change the last character of the token/signature the JWT is still valid. E.g. the following token do all validate correctly:
`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJTb21lIFRlc3QiLCJjbGFpbSI6IlNvbWUgQ2xhaW0ifQ.UkFYSK7hSSeiqUOSMdbXgbOErMFnuK0Emk1722ny-r4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJTb21lIFRlc3QiLCJjbGFpbSI6IlNvbWUgQ2xhaW0ifQ.UkFYSK7hSSeiqUOSMdbXgbOErMFnuK0Emk1722ny-r5
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJTb21lIFRlc3QiLCJjbGFpbSI6IlNvbWUgQ2xhaW0ifQ.UkFYSK7hSSeiqUOSMdbXgbOErMFnuK0Emk1722ny-r6
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJTb21lIFRlc3QiLCJjbGFpbSI6IlNvbWUgQ2xhaW0ifQ.UkFYSK7hSSeiqUOSMdbXgbOErMFnuK0Emk1722ny-r7`

I have checked this on http://jwt.io/ and can be reproduced in my .Net application as well.

Can someone explain how it is possible that the signature is not unique for a given payload? I understand that collisions can occur, but I cannot explain that they are consecutive sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this special case **you are changing the base64 url encoding of the signature, not the signature itself**

The fourth base64 values encode the same binary value. Try converting to hexadecimal at http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_b64udec.html

The value you will see is

```
52415848aee14927a2a9439231d6d781b384acc167b8ad049a4d7bdb69f2fabe
```

If you change the suffix to `-r1` or `-r8` then the binary value changes and signature validation  will fail

[Can two different BASE 64 encoded strings result into same string if decoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449595/can-two-different-base-64-encoded-strings-result-into-same-string-if-decoded/38513081#38513081)

Answer (score 0):

When you change the signature (the last part) you can still decode the JWT to see the header and payload. However, if you attempt to validate the JWT with the changed signature, that validation will fail.

Comment: That is not true. Because you change the _signature_. The signature itself is obviously not part of the signature itself. So you can change the signature and still have a valid message. That is what this whole question was about. Apparently this is inherent to how base64 behaves. This means that you have different token with exactly the same payload with different signatures, but all valid.

Comment: I am not understanding 'you can still have a valid message'. Yes you can still 'decode' the JwtHeader and JwtPayload, but the process of validating the JWT requires ensuring that the 'signature' matches up with the JwtHeader and JwtPayload. So no, the JWT will not be considered valid and libraries should reject it.